# Issue importing modules when using a remote jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, remote-access, pythonpath

I am using Jupiter notebook remotely using my university's server. I used the technique that gives you a token which you then use to log on with your local machine. When I tried to run my code I get an error message saying

```
Out[] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I have a feeling its something to do with the python environment path. I would welcome any help.

Thanks

```
import NumPy

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d4cdadb62aa7> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy is not installed..

you can install numpy by using the below command in jupyter notebook

```
!pip install numpy
```

if at all it fails, use

```
!pip3 install numpy
```

! mark informs jupyter kernel to run as system command